# Import csv file to DataTable and bind columns with Chart

Tags: c#, charts, datatable, mschart

Please tell me if I am missing some settings that I need to set.
As in my graph I am getting  column values in my x asis and not 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7  8 9

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {       

        chart1.DataSource = csvData;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 10;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = -5;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 5;

        chart1.Series["Series2"].YValueMembers = "Column name";
        chart1.Series["Series2"].XValueMember = "Column name";
        chart1.DataBind();

    }




}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
    DataTable dtCloned = csvData.Clone();
    dtCloned.Columns["column name"].DataType = typeof(double);
    dtCloned.Columns["column name"].DataType = typeof(double);

    chart1.DataSource = dtCloned;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 10;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = -5;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 5;

    chart1.Series["Series2"].YValueMembers = "Delta_Sigma";
    chart1.Series["Series2"].XValueMember = "CpK_Refrence";
    chart1.DataBind();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Ah ok I understand your issue now. The issue is that when you are reading the data from the csv it is adding all the data as string and the chart is then reading the values as string thats why none of the `Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Maximum = 10` changes the axis.

You need to change how the data is read from the csv. In essence you need to add

```
csvData.Columns["CpK_Refrence"].DataType = GetType(Integer)
```

before any data is added to the datatable **[you cannot change a column type once data has been added].** if all your columns are going to numbers then change the below so all your columns are numeric columns

```
DataColumn datecolumn = new DataColumn(column);
'TO
DataColumn datecolumn = new DataColumn("Column1", typeof(double));
```

Comment: I am not able to edit the statements it says datecolumn already belongs.

Comment: How do I clone the table and change the Datatype of column to double? will that work

Comment: Yeah Thank you for your precise advice It is working now that I cloned it and changed the datatype

Comment: as i said you cannot change a column type once data has been added. Creating a new datatable and adding the columns of the old datatable [but making them of some number type] etc. will work. The essential thing is not to have string entries